# Check and delete duplicates Parse.com class

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I have a class in parse called testItem here is a snap shot of this class

[image]

As you can see the same item comes up multiple time but that is fine because it is at different schools and dining halls, but this item comes up twice at the same diningHallNumber and school so it is a duplicate, Oven Roast Potates is at diningHallNumber: 1 and Union College twice so it is a duplicate. So I am trying to write a could code function to remove this. Here is what I have so far:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("removeDuplicateItems", function(request, response) {

function checkDuplicate(school) {

    var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
    var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
    testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', schoolArray[i]);


    testItemsQuery.each(function(testItem) {
        var item = testItem.get('item');
        var school = testItem.get('school');
        var diningHallNum = testItem.get('diningHallNumber');

        var testItemsQueryCheck = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
        testItemsQueryCheck.equalTo ('item', item);
        testItemsQueryCheck.equalTo ('school', school);
        testItemsQueryCheck.equalTo ('diningHallNumber', diningHallNum);
        //then delete Item

}
var schoolArray = ['Union College (NY)', 'University of Albany', 'Rensselaer Polytechnic Institute'];

for (var i = 0; i < schoolArray.length; i++) {  
    checkDuplicate(schoolArray[i]);
}
}
```

but this doesn't work because it will always come true I need a way to see if this is the second time this item has come up. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880781/parse-com-find-all-objects-belonging-to-a-user-with-objectid

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes im not quite sure how this fully relates to what I am asking

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Im more trying to check if there is a duplicate, and remove it.

Comment: the duplicate entries are 2nd and 3rd right ? you want to delete one and keep one?

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes right i only want to delete the duplicate and keep the others

Answer (score 11):

You can use a hash table to keep track of the duplicate items. Something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("removeDuplicateItems", function(request, status) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var _ = require("underscore");

  var hashTable = {};

  function hashKeyForTestItem(testItem) {
    var fields = ["item", "meal", "schoolMenu", "diningHallNumber", "school"];
    var hashKey = "";
    _.each(fields, function (field) {
        hashKey += testItem.get(field) + "/" ;
    });
    return hashKey;
  }

  var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query("TestItem");
  testItemsQuery.each(function (testItem) {
    var key = hashKeyForTestItem(testItem);

    if (key in hashTable) { // this item was seen before, so destroy this
        return testItem.destroy();
    } else { // it is not in the hashTable, so keep it
        hashTable[key] = 1;
    }

  }).then(function() {
    status.success("Migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong.");
  });
});
```

Comment: This works great, Is there a way to keep the oldest duplicate?