# How to get userId as a pointer from "_User" object?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have the user objects in variable userObjects.
I will later use the userIdPointer to search for a query in another class.

```
var userIdPointer = [];
for(var i = 0; i < userObjects.length; i++) {
    userIdPointer.push(userObjects[i].id);
}
```

This method only gets the ids, but I want it as a pointer.

Comment: here is something that may help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880781/parse-com-find-all-objects-belonging-to-a-user-with-objectid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to get direct pointer like

```
var userIdPointer = [];
for(var i = 0; i < userObjects.length; i++) {
    var userPointer =  {__type: "Pointer", className: "User", objectId: userObjects[i].id};
    userIdPointer.push(userPointer);
}
```

Another way is to get the objectId and create user object yourself

```
var userIdPointer = [];
for(var i = 0; i < userObjects.length; i++) {
    userIdPointer.push(userObjects[i]);
}

userId = userObjects[c].id;
```

or

```
var userIds = [];
for(var i = 0; i < userObjects.length; i++) {
    userIds.push(userObjects[i].id);
}

userId = userIds[c];
```

than

```
var user = new Parse.User();
user.id = userId;

var query = new Parse.Query('Your_Class');
query.equalTo('user', user); // userpointer class
```